# Converting OracleParameter (Output) of type Decimal to C#.Net decimal Type

Tags: c#, .net, oracle11g, type-conversion

I have a Stored Procedure that return money value in its Output parameter.
Is there some straight approach to get the returned value within the parameter and put it into a c# decimal variable?

I'm doing this:

//Replacing the "." by "," and then doing the conversion.
decimal myValue = decimal.Parse(vlr.Replace(".",","))

If you have some tip to get it better, I would appreciate your help.

thanks in advance,

Comment: What does the `Value` property give you?

Comment: Value = "1234.12" for example, if I try a Convert.ToDecimal , it loses its floating point like this "123412"

Comment: So the value is definitely a string? You can use `decimal.Parse(text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` to avoid culture issues getting in the way, but it would be better not to have to parse it...